# Host key verification failed

Tags: ssh

Использую VPS от DigitalOcean.
Сначала сгенерировал ssh ключ: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Потом добавил его в security самого дроплета, предварительно скопировав его таким образом: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
При коннекте по `ssh root@[your.ip.address.here]` выбрасывает исключение:

> Host key verification failed

Из-за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 1):

> при коннекте по `ssh root@[your.ip.address.here]` выбрасывает - *Host key verification failed*. Из-за чего это может быть?

из-за того, что слепок (*fingerprint*) ключа, которым вторая сторона (`[your.ip.address.here]`) предлагает шифровать данные, не совпадает с сохранённым слепком.

возможно, изменение ключа второй стороной как-то связано с вашими действиями — *добавил его в security самого дроплета*. не имею ни малейшего представления о том, что это за «дроплет», и что у него может быть за «security», но [если вы уверены](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed/h), что так и должно было быть, то можете удалить предыдущий сохранённый слепок:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R [your.ip.address.here]
```

Comment: Попытался удалить  _предыдущий сохранённый слепок_ и выкидывает исключение ввиде: Host [your.ip.address.here] not found in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: _возможно, изменение ключа второй стороной как-то связано с вашими действиями — добавил его в security самого дроплета. не имею ни малейшего представления о том, что это за «дроплет», и что у него может быть за «security»_ - таким образом мы сообщаем серверу свой публичный ssh ключ

Comment: @dev.user, приведите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки полностью. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав «править» ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: я в курсе как править вопрос) ошибку полностью и написал, еще раз могу написать  : _Host key verification failed_

Comment: кстати и мне пришлось самому создавать known_hosts, так как он у меня отсутствовал, но за то появился какой-то known_hosts.ZXt8IKEKO3

Comment: может детальное описание процессов при ssh конекта поможет? ввиде ssh **-v** root@[your.ip.address.here]

Comment: @dev.user, возможно. но если уж увеличивать *verbosity*, то до максимума: `ssh -vvv ...`